# Arduino Yún causing power suge warning

Tags: arduino-yun

Recently I got an Arduino Yún board that sends out a power surge error message everytime I connect it to my laptop through the USB cable. I tried two Arduino Leonardo and one Arduino Uno and there wasn't any problem with them or the USB port. Am I missing something or is the board faulty already?

Answer (score 1):

Use a USB tester to test the current consumption, it should be < 500ma

I recommend using a USB that has power of its own, eg. monitor USB

Answer (score 0):

Yún boards are more powerful boards than your average Arduino. Probably too powerful for your little laptop's USB ports. Use a powered hub or an external power supply to run the board.